# Why store a salt along side the hashed password?

Tags: hash, appsec, credentials

Understand the need to protection credentials with hashes that are expensive and to use cryptographically random salts.

What I would like to understand is why you would store the salt along side the hash in the database, does this not defeat the point of having one?

Take a SQL injection vulnerability in which I can dump the data in the User table. If I have access to the Hash as well as the salt does it not make my brute force attempt easier (as apposed to not knowing the salt?).

If storing the salt with the hash - does this not defeat the point of protection against rainbow attacks? (if an attacker has access to the database).

Comment: What you are discussing is called "pepper". You can read about it at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3272/password-hashing-add-salt-pepper-or-is-salt-enough

Comment: I'm not referring to a pepper (it is not constant for each and every record) - I'm asking about a per record salt that is not made up of a cryptographically random value - rather a concatenated value of each record such as the ID Column + username + date of birth or whatever.

Comment: The purpose of the salt is to make the use of rainbow tables infeasible.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420843/how-does-password-salt-help-against-a-rainbow-table-attack for more info.

Comment: Thaanks @mti2935 - so does storing the salt alongside the hash not defeat the point of protecting against rainbow tables - does it make it easier for an attacker to crack the password using a rainbow table if they have the salt?

Comment: The point of a salt is to ensure that work done to crack one password cannot be reused to crack a different password. The point of a rainbow table is reuse of work through precomputation. Additionally, a static value like database ID, username, etc are *not* suitable for salts as new salts must be used any time a user changes their password.

Comment: To say it another way, a rainbow table would likely contain the hash for the password 12345.  But, it's highly unlikely that the rainbow table would contain the hash for eac53dde9661daf47a428efea28c81a021c06d64f98eeabbdcff442d992153a8:12345 (where eac5...53a8 is a randomly-generated salt).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I can see where you're coming from, but the answer is basically "that's not what the salt is for".  If I'm trying to discover a *particular user*'s password, the salt doesn't help much if it's right beside the hash.  However, it's not *expected* to be useful in that situation - cracking an individual user's password is difficult enough already.

The point of the salt is that it's something to add to each password before hashing such that each password is unique - if two users both have `hunter2` as their password, the hashes need to be different.

Say an attacker is fishing through a database (or a whole range of databases) to find everyone whose password is `letmein123`.  Without a salt, they can do the hash once and search for the hash.

Without a salt if an attacker spots two or more identical hashes in the database, it indicates that this is a weak password (since multiple users have chosen the same one) and can concentrate on cracking this first.

But the salt is a user-specific prefix/suffix that is added to the password before hashing, so (even with a "public" salt) an attacker has to re-calculate the hash for every user - so checking one password against 10000 users isn't any more efficient than checking 10000 passwords against one user, which is the point.

Comment: That makes sense. Does storing the salt alongside the hash make it easier to brute force the password?

Comment: That's not the threat salts are designed and intended to protect against. A door lock doesn't prevent someone from opening your window.

Comment: Great - so using a strong hashing technique will hopefully save you in this case - and storing the salt alongside the hash does not make your hash any weaker.

Comment: Is *hunter2* a reference to this [bash.org's quote](http://www.bash.org/?244321)? ☺

Comment: @A.L always. :)

Comment: 4th para -`Without a salt if an attacker spots two or more identical hashes in the database, it indicates that this is a weak password (since multiple users have chosen the same one) and can concentrate on cracking this first.` - without a salt, if attacker finds 2 more identical hashes in the db, then he has most probably already cracked password, right?

Comment: @ajaysinghnegi If the attacker starts by looking for any hash which is repeated a lot, then they would know that the password is the same for all those users, without necessarily knowing what that shared password is.  But if multiple users used the same password, it's probably a simpler one which is easier to brute-force.