# Should password hashes be encrypted or HMACed?

Tags: encryption, passwords, hmac

Assume I am hashing user passwords with PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt, or some other secure key derivation function.

Are there:

1. tangible security benefits,
2. precedents, and
3. respected research

for protecting these hashes from offline attacks by either encrypting the hashes or otherwise applying a secret key to them via, say, an HMAC?

I believe [this previous post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3165/hmac-why-not-hmac-for-password-storage) attempted to ask a similar question, but the question was unclear and treated by most responders as if it asked whether or not *passwords themselves* should be HMACed instead of being passed through a salted KDF first.

Comment: encryption does not provide authentication.  This question is erratic.

Comment: With all due respect, my question was not about authentication, but about protecting verifiers from offline attacks (e.g., the salt/password database being leaked). I understand that creating your own homemade constructs based upon secure cryptographic primitives can weaken or entirely defeat security through unintended and unintuitive means. Hence I further asked if there was precedent and/or research supporting this type of approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Encryption, or a deterministic MAC, may offer you an extra gain of security on the off-chance that the attacker could grab the database of hashed-and-encrypted passwords but *not* the encryption/MAC key (which the same server must necessarily know to do his job). Some people call that "pepper" (as a pun with the notion of "salt" -- IT security people are a bunch of joyous fellows). See [this previous question on the subject](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3272/password-hashing-add-salt-pepper-or-is-salt-enough).

Since the scenario is rather restrictive, and using a key implies dealing with key management issues, I would recommend not to bother.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say it's an off-chance. And even with key management issues, is there any reason to believe that an additional HMAC step would *decrease* security? Even assuming the worst-case scenario of your key becoming publicly exposed.

Comment: HMAC with a non pathological hash function (i.e. HMAC with SHA-256, SHA-1 or even MD5) should not decrease the security of a password-hashing scheme.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any particular advantage to an HMAC versus encryption versus including a pepper when hashing the password and salt (ignoring for a moment that PKBDF2, bcrypt, and scrypt have no formal pepper parameter, which would lead me to discourage that approach). My intuition is that an HMAC is a better choice here.

Comment: HMAC is hard to get wrong: no randomness, simple API, already implemented in various frameworks. That is a very strong reason to prefer HMAC.

Comment: If you're interested to know, I ended up going with an AEAD mode of AES rather than HMAC. The rationale being that bcrypt digests canonically contain the algorithm version, salt, and digest in a single string. That information would be lost if HMAC'd, making it impossible to actually verify a password against it. Thus, I chose reversible encryption rather than having to deal with splitting out the pieces and reassembling them later.

Comment: In hindsight, HMACing the password *before* applying a password hash comes with all the advantages of a MAC (simplicity, strong conceptual alignment) with none of the disadvantages. Were I to make this decision again today, I would go that route.